# How to generate mock data in a variable of a class that has a nested class

Tags: c#

What are the different way to put mock data inside the variable “jokes” using this ‘var jokes = new Jokes();’
I would love to learn more about this. Could you please share some resources too? What concept do I need to focus on to understand this?

```
 public class Jokes
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Value value { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string joke { get; set; }
    public List<string> categories { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How did you do it for the non nested class? Do the same for the nested class. Then assign the newly created class to the Value property of your instance of a Jokes class. If you struggle with that, edit your attempt into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Mock data is generally using for software testing. For this task there are libraries. When add a library, you can call it with your properties for example;

For this properties:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

When you download [bogus](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus) library you can create mock data like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    Randomizer.Seed = new Random(123456);
    var ordergenerator = new Faker<Order>()
        .RuleFor(o => o.Id, Guid.NewGuid)
        .RuleFor(o => o.Date, f => f.Date.Past(3))
        .RuleFor(o => o.OrderValue, f => f.Finance.Amount(0, 10000))
        .RuleFor(o => o.Shipped, f => f.Random.Bool(0.9f));
    var customerGenerator = new Faker<Customer>()
        .RuleFor(c => c.Id, Guid.NewGuid())
        .RuleFor(c => c.Name, f => f.Company.CompanyName())
        .RuleFor(c => c.Address, f => f.Address.FullAddress())
        .RuleFor(c => c.City, f => f.Address.City())
        .RuleFor(c => c.Country, f => f.Address.Country())
        .RuleFor(c => c.ZipCode, f => f.Address.ZipCode())
        .RuleFor(c => c.Phone, f => f.Phone.PhoneNumber())
        .RuleFor(c => c.Email, f => f.Internet.Email())
        .RuleFor(c => c.ContactName, (f, c) => f.Name.FullName())
        .RuleFor(c => c.Orders, f => ordergenerator.Generate(f.Random.Number(10)).ToList());
    return customerGenerator.Generate(100);
}
```

For more info:
[Link1](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/697006/Creating-mock-data-for-software-testing)
[Link2](https://blogs.msmvps.com/bsonnino/2019/04/24/creating-sample-data-for-c/)